# Removing number from for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a question about Matlab.

My chunk of code looks like this:

```
piece = 1:25;
piece([12]) = [];

for sub = 1:(valid_subject)
    group_data = [];
    for j = 1:length(piece)
        group_data = [group_data; subject_data{sub}.trial{j}'];
    end
    group_mat(:,:,1,sub) = group_data
end
```

What I want to do is to loop through all trials, from 1 to 25, but omitting trial 12. By using length(piece) I just go through 24 numbers, from 1 to 24. Do you know another way to have numbers from 1 to 25 without 12 as j?

Thank you!

Comment: You want to do `for j = piece`.

Comment: I tried this one, but then I get an error "Index exceeds array bounds"

Comment: "Index exceeds array bounds" is a different problem. With `for j = piece` you iterate over the numbers 1 through 25, excluding 12, as you are looking to do. Put a `disp(j)` in the loop to assure yourself that this is the case.

Comment: this loop `for j = 1:length(piece) group_data = [group_data; subject_data{sub}.trial{j}'];end` runs 24 laps, these rounds being `[1 2 3 .. 11 12 13 .. 22 23 24]` but holholhol needs `[1 2 3 .. 11 13 .. 22 23 24 25]`. Since `piece` already contains `[1 2 3 .. 11 13 .. 22 23 24 25]` all that is needed is to use `for j=piece` instead of `for j=1:length(piece)`

Answer (score -3):

You have modified `piece` removing 1 item therefore piece now only has 24 elements and you are telling the `for` loop to follow `[1:1:length(piece)]`

Instead of `for j=1:length(piece)` use `for j=1:piece`

Comment: With `piece` as defined in the question, this loop will execute exactly once.

Comment: This is not correct. As I said in the comment underneath the question, the right syntax is `for j = piece`. `1:piece` is the same as `1:piece(1)`, which is the same as `1`.

Comment: "in MATLAB j=piece is same as j=1:piece" No, it's not. I suggest you try it out and see what you get.

Comment: In fact, I'll do it for you: https://ideone.com/GCltm8

Comment: .. in the context of a for loop indeed they are the same

Comment: @JohnBG Can you post some sample code and the corresponding output that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Have you actually run this code, or are you going by guesswork? It is good to be stubborn, but this is an easily falsifiable statement, and you are arguing with two people that actually tried this out to be sure of their stance.

Comment: in MATLAB the following are exactly the same for k=piece  .. end; and for k=1:piece(end)  end; .. and for k=1:1:p1(end) .. end;